# Pass obtained field to another (nested) query in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

Imagine the following query:

```
query {
  user {
    id
  }
  SomeOtherStuff(id: <--- I want to pass the id obtained from user) {
    id
  }
}
```

How do you pass a parameter obtained from one query to another ?

Comment: You haven't indicated what language and GraphQL client you are using, or whether you are working with an existing API or one that you are designing yourself. This information would be helpful in providing a more thorough answer to your question.

Comment: @DanielRearden I am using apollo

Comment: I'm learing and running into a lot of similar questions. This link proved helpful for my GraphQL query-fu: https://devhints.io/graphql

Comment: I think you should rename your question and change the query to "nested query", then you might get what you are actually looking for. @AdamWolski

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In GraphQL, fields at each "level" of the request are executed and resolved in parallel. In your example, `user` and `SomeOtherStuff` are both fields of the same type (the root `Query` type) -- so they will be resolved at the same time. That means each query essentially is not aware of the other or what the other resolved to.

You would have to handle this kind of scenario client side. In other words, request the user first, parse the response for the id and then make the second request.

Edit: In Apollo, you would utilize compose for this purpose:

```
const userQuery = gql`query User { user { id } }`;
const stuffQuery = gql`query SomeOtherStuff($id: ID) { someOtherStuff(id: $id){ stuff } }`;

export default compose(
  graphql(userQuery, { name: 'userData' })
  graphql(stuffQuery, { name: 'stuffData', options: ({userData:{id}={}}) => ({variables: {id}}) }),
)(YourComponent)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is quite not what I expected from GraphQL. I thought that the idea of combining multiple requests into one was the GraphQL main principle. It seems pretty basic scenario for me, to get some other data that depend on the user but are not nested in the user itself... Is there any way you can get the data that depends on the user and are not nested in the user type  (in the same request )?

Comment: Short answer: no. I would venture to say being forced to deal with the situation you describe is indicative of poor API design. The point is, if there is data related to the user, it *should* be part of the User type. If the data is relating to the currently logged in user (viewer), there should probably be a context-aware viewer query that lets you access it without having to first fetch an ID for the viewer first.

Comment: if you use compose, will the two queries get executed within a single request-response pair  ?

Comment: Because this answer mentions apollo, they provide 3 options for handling this scenario in this post: https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/using-apollo-link-to-handle-dependent-queries/

Comment: @AndyGarcia upvoted your comment as you provide a link of official blog talks about this topic.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @DanielRearden. You should make type-resolvers so you can go infinitely deep into the graph. I made a simple server example [here](https://github.com/konsumer/simple-graphql/) that shows deep relationships. Because all the noun-fields are references, it goes infinitely deep for any query.

With that server, you can run a query like this, for example:

```
{
  hero {
    name
    friends {
      name
      friends {
        name
        friends {
          name
          friends: {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, in your example, structure it like this:

```
query {
  user {
    id
    otherStuff {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I was looking for same scenario and landed on this question. You can get it work other way around. It all depends how you have written your graphql resolver and you need to make sure that your database relations are intact. I have got it working like this.

[image]